# json decode issue backtesting with zipline

Tags: json, python-3.x, zipline, back-testing

I'm running the test code below on ubuntu server.  I'm trying to back test a simple buy and hold strategy with zipline.  I'm just trying to make sure I've got everything installed correctly to back test.  I'm pretty new to zipline.  I'm getting the error below and not sure why.

I'm following the steps in this blog post:

https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-backtesting-trading-strategies-7afae611a35e

I'm running the code in a jupyter notebook.

when I run the code before to verify the bundle has been ingested this is what it shows:

code:

```
!zipline bundles
```

output:

```
apple-prices-2017-2019 2020-06-06 20:33:05.356288
apple-prices-2017-2019 2020-06-05 06:33:39.834841
apple-prices-2017-2019 2020-06-05 06:29:53.091904
apple-prices-2017-2019 2020-06-05 06:26:56.583051
csvdir <no ingestions>
quandl 2020-06-06 20:25:58.737940
quandl 2020-06-06 20:18:01.977412
quantopian-quandl 2020-06-04 16:15:57.717373
quantopian-quandl 2020-05-29 05:59:54.967114
```

the code I'm running in the jupyter notebook is below, along with the error.  does anyone see what the issue is, and can you suggest how to fix?

code:

```
%%zipline --start 2016-1-1 --end 2017-12-31 --capital-base 1050.0 -o buy_and_hold.pkl

# imports
from zipline.api import order, symbol, record

# parameters
selected_stock = 'AAPL'
n_stocks_to_buy = 10

def initialize(context):
    context.has_ordered = False  

def handle_data(context, data):
    # record price for further inspection
    record(price=data.current(symbol(selected_stock), 'price'))

    # trading logic
    if not context.has_ordered:
        # placing order, negative number for sale/short
        order(symbol(selected_stock), n_stocks_to_buy)
        # setting up a flag for holding a position
        context.has_ordered = True
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d11030c42e8b> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('zipline', '--start 2016-1-1 --end 2017-12-31 --capital-base 1050.0 -o buy_and_hold.pkl', "\n# imports\nfrom zipline.api import order, symbol, record\n\n# parameters\nselected_stock = 'AAPL'\nn_stocks_to_buy = 10\n\ndef initialize(context):\n    context.has_ordered = False  \n\ndef handle_data(context, data):\n    # record price for further inspection\n    record(price=data.current(symbol(selected_stock), 'price'))\n    \n    # trading logic\n    if not context.has_ordered:\n        # placing order, negative number for sale/short\n        order(symbol(selected_stock), n_stocks_to_buy)\n        # setting up a flag for holding a position\n        context.has_ordered = True")

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2165             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2166             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2167                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2168             return result
   2169 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__main__.py in zipline_magic(line, cell)
    309             '%s%%zipline' % ((cell or '') and '%'),
    310             # don't use system exit and propogate errors to the caller
--> 311             standalone_mode=False,
    312         )
    313     except SystemExit as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in main(self, args, prog_name, complete_var, standalone_mode, **extra)
    780             try:
    781                 with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
--> 782                     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
    783                     if not standalone_mode:
    784                         return rv

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in invoke(self, ctx)
   1064         _maybe_show_deprecated_notice(self)
   1065         if self.callback is not None:
-> 1066             return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
   1067 
   1068 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in invoke(*args, **kwargs)
    608         with augment_usage_errors(self):
    609             with ctx:
--> 610                 return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    611 
    612     def forward(*args, **kwargs):  # noqa: B902

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/decorators.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     19 
     20     def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
---> 21         return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
     22 
     23     return update_wrapper(new_func, f)

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__main__.py in run(ctx, algofile, algotext, define, data_frequency, capital_base, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, blotter)
    274         local_namespace=local_namespace,
    275         environ=os.environ,
--> 276         blotter=blotter,
    277     )
    278 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py in _run(handle_data, initialize, before_trading_start, analyze, algofile, algotext, defines, data_frequency, capital_base, data, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, environ, blotter)
    157             trading_calendar=trading_calendar,
    158             trading_day=trading_calendar.day,
--> 159             trading_days=trading_calendar.schedule[start:end].index,
    160         )
    161         first_trading_day =\

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/finance/trading.py in __init__(self, load, bm_symbol, exchange_tz, trading_calendar, trading_day, trading_days, asset_db_path, future_chain_predicates, environ)
    101             trading_day,
    102             trading_days,
--> 103             self.bm_symbol,
    104         )
    105 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/data/loader.py in load_market_data(trading_day, trading_days, bm_symbol, environ)
    147         # date so that we can compute returns for the first date.
    148         trading_day,
--> 149         environ,
    150     )
    151     tc = ensure_treasury_data(

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/data/loader.py in ensure_benchmark_data(symbol, first_date, last_date, now, trading_day, environ)
    214 
    215     try:
--> 216         data = get_benchmark_returns(symbol)
    217         data.to_csv(get_data_filepath(filename, environ))
    218     except (OSError, IOError, HTTPError):

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/data/benchmarks.py in get_benchmark_returns(symbol)
     33         'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/chart/5y'.format(symbol)
     34     )
---> 35     data = r.json()
     36 
     37     df = pd.DataFrame(data)

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    894                     # used.
    895                     pass
--> 896         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    897 
    898     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this post solve my problem.  only needed the first two steps listed in it.  you need to update the benchmarks.py and loader.py files in zipline/data

[Getting JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) with Python + Zipline + Docker + Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957791/getting-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-with-python)